# How to check if metal is supported?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit

How to check if Metal is supported on iOS / macOS ? I saw that many users recommend checking if the return of `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` is nil, but I have one system where `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` return an object, but Metal is not supported on this system. So how to check if Metal is available on the system ?

Comment: I have found `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` to be reliable on iOS at least. What are the details of your problem system (device type, OS version)? Is it possible that your assumption that about it not supporting metal is incorrect?

Comment: @Columbo I tried on MacOS inside a vmware that do not support metal, i confirm you that MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice return an object but that metal is not working on this machine